# Binary vs non-binary hidden layer output

Tags: python, neural-network

I'm trying to understand exactly how to implement a basic neural network in python that will use genetic algorithms for unsupervised learning and have ran into a small problem that the literature I've been able to pull up hasn't solved.

Lets say I have an input of 2 values, that are passed to a 3 neuron hidden layer with all weights/biases applied. After I determine if it fired I now send what exactly? Do I send the output from my sigmoid or do I send a full stop/start. In other words is my output into hidden layer 2 going to be binary or is it non-binary?

Can anyone explain this with the reasoning behind we choose one or the other?

Comment: What do you mean by 'full stop/start'?

Comment: As in 1 or 0. So I have a neuron on the first hidden layer containing a value of 0.65 (after my sigmoid has collapsed it), which is above my threshold so I fire the neuron. Is the output 1, or is it 0.65 and why?

Answer (score 2):

This really depends on your network design, but there is no such restriction that inputs have to be binary. In fact that will not be a case you face often. For output layer, the type of output can be easily and clearly determined, eg. if you have something like a classifier that classifies this answer is spam or not, then the output (of 'a single neuron' output layer) will be binary. If you have a neural network to recognise handwritten digits, then probably it's better to have a 10 neuron output layer, each giving probability of the input image being one of the digits [0, 9].

For other layers (hidden and input), the output can be anything, most of the time it won't be binary.

**EDIT**:

I think I misunderstood your question a bit, and also you probably aren't talking about [Fuzzy Neural Networks](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Fuzzy_neural_network).

So if you are not considering those (in most cases), when you say a neuron has fired, you mean its output is 1 (binary high), and 0 otherwise, so yes it's binary.

> Do I send the output from my sigmoid or do I send a full stop/start

The way sigmoid function is used in neural networks (with weights) it attempts to make the computation output a binary result, so basically both the options mean the same. There is a difference, but usually NNs try to avoid that region where sigmoid (or related neuron) outputs some value which can not be approximated to 0 or 1 nicely. Weights of inputs of that neuron are moved so that the neuron gives a clear 0 or 1.

Also note that, while it's not good to not know sigmoid (and tanh), but for practical purposes [ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), Leaky ReLU, or maxout are better choices.

Suggested: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-1/
Also you can find lectures (videos and notes) by Andrew Ng, Andrej Karpathy etc helpful.

Comment: I understand input and output design specifications, I was mainly wondering about the hidden layer outputs, rather than the final layer output. That being said is there a reason why you would want to use binary output on hidden layers? It's just my assumption, but I believe that having a non-binary output on the hidden layers would allow for better results overall.